# Passar variável Javascript para corpo PHP

Tags: php, javascript, select, input

Vou tentar passar o maior número de detalhes possível sobre o meu problema. Eu tenho um select em HTML que puxa seus options diretamente do banco de dados, conforme o código abaixo:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sindigrejinha') or die ('Falha ao conectar-se com DB');
$result = $conn->query("select idTransportador, Nome_Uso from transportador");
echo "<select id='listaTransp' onchange='alimentarCampo();' class='form-control' name='idTransportador'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($idTransportador, $Nome_Uso);
    $idTransportador = $row['idTransportador'];
    $Nome_Uso = $row['Nome_Uso']; 
    echo '<option value="'.$idTransportador.'">'.$Nome_Uso.'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
```

Dependendo da option escolhida, o value de um input é alterado usando os códigos abaixo.

### Input:

```
echo '<input id="inputMotor" class="form-control">';
```

### Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alimentarCampo() {
        var listaTransp = document.getElementById("listaTransp");
        document.getElementById("inputMotor").value = listaTransp.options[listaTransp.selectedIndex].value;
}
</script>
```

Até aí tudo bem.  **O problema**, é que o valor que é enviado para o input é o do "idTransportador", e precisaria ser do "Nome_Condutor" que no caso é outro atributo da tabela "transportador". Eu **NÃO** posso alterar o value das options para $Nome_Condutor, pois elas serão usadas em um form de outra página (isso não é relevante).

**A pergunta é:** Como eu posso, usando o valor de "idTransportador", mostrar o "Nome_Condutor" respectivo dentro do input?

Comment: `Nome_Condutor` é o `Nome_Uso`?

Comment: Não. 'Nome_Uso' é outro atributo da tabela que será mostrada nas options do select, mas com isso está tudo certo.

Comment: Mas esse `Nome_Condutor` não está sendo selecionado na query. De onde ele vem?

Comment: Ele não está sendo selecionado na query, realmente, mas ele é um atributo da tabela 'transportador' também. Eu preciso dar um "apelido" (que seria o Nome_Condutor) ao idTransportador e mostrar ele no input.

Comment: Então, você pode incluir essa coluna no SELECT, e usar o que sugeri na resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se for possível trazer o nome do condutor na mesma query, eu o colocaria dentro de um *data attribute*:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($idTransportador, $Nome_Uso);
    $idTransportador = $row['idTransportador'];
    $Nome_Uso = $row['Nome_Uso']; 
    $Nome_Condutor = $row['Nome_Condutor']; 
    echo '<option value="'.$idTransportador.'" data-nome-condutor="'.$Nome_Condutor.'">'.$Nome_Uso.'</option>';
}
```

Aí no JS é só fazer assim:

```
function alimentarCampo() {
    var listaTransp = document.getElementById("listaTransp");
    document.getElementById("inputMotor").value = listaTransp.options[listaTransp.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-nome-condutor');
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom, de nada!