# Enviar valor de uma variável em Javascript para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho procurado muito e feito muitos testes mas não estou conseguindo enviar o valor de uma variável do Javascript para uma variável PHP.

O meu caso é o seguinte: Tenho um portal de imóveis e gostaria de pegar as informações (mais precisamente os dados da imobiliária ou apenas o nome dela) buscadas por uma função Javascript e passar para uma variável no PHP, no caso a variável `$title`, que é a variável que regula o título que aparecerá em cada página no navegador.

A função JS que pega essas informações é essa:

```
function getDadosImobiliaria(id) {
$.getJSON('../site/Control/controlUsuario.php', {type: 'selectDadosImob', imobiliariaId: id}, function(data) {
    if (data.tipo == "f") {
        var imobiliaria = data.nome+" "+data.sobrenome;
        $('.nomeAnunciante').html(imobiliaria);
    } else {
        var imobiliaria = data.sobrenome;

        $('.nomeAnunciante').html(imobiliaria);
    }

    $('#logoAnunciante').attr('src', 'imagensUpload/'+data.logo);
    $('.ruaNumero').html(data.rua+', '+data.numero);
    $('.bairro').html(data.bairro);
    $('.cidadeUf').html(data.cidade+' - '+data.uf);
    $('#fone').html(data.fone);
    $('.showCidade').html(data.cidade);
    $('.showCidade').attr('href', '/imobiliarias/'+data.cidade);
    $('.countTotalImoveis').html(data.count);

    if (data.creci != undefined) {
        $('.creci').html("CRECI: "+data.creci);
    }

}); 
}
```

Como posso fazer para passar a variável da imobiliária ou qualquer outra variável para a variável do PHP `$title` contida em um outro arquivo e assim formar os títulos das páginas do portal de imóveis? Por `POST`? Ajax?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: O único objetivo é alterar o título?

Comment: Poste o código da pagina em php também. Pode ajudar a achar a soluçao.

Comment: Mas se for só alterar o title use o famoso... document.title = "titulo"

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar variável Javascript para corpo PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27130/passar-vari%c3%a1vel-javascript-para-corpo-php)

Comment: Andrei, o único objetivo é alterar o título. Ele precisa ser dinâmico para melhorar o SEO das páginas. E o código PHP praticamente não tem, fiz testes apenas com a variável $title recebendo o valor. Como não sou muito da área de programação, não consegui prosseguir. Usei o document.title depois de ver que você sugeriu, mas também não deu certo. Quero apenas conseguir passar essa variável do JS para o PHP. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: A variável `imobiliaria` é o valor que você quer que contenha no `<title>`?

Comment: Mas você quer enviar ao PHP ou pegar via ajax e injetar na <title> com JS? Sua pergunta esta bem confusa, edite ela e explique o que realmente quer.

Comment: Sim Andrei, a variável imobiliaria é o valor que quero passar pro title.

Comment: Guilherme, eu antes queria ou enviar por PHP, seja do jeito que for (ajax, post e tudo que for possível) ou, por JS mesmo, setar o title com a variável imobiliaria. Eu consegui fazer isso depois de muito testar, mas, infelizmente, setando por JS o título da página, não aparece o título que fiz por JS ao pesquisar no google, ou seja, não é relevante setar por JS o SEO da página. Então terei que fazer por PHP para ter relevância para o google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois que olhei melhor o seu código reparei que você estava utilizando o `jquery`. Existe uma forma de você enviar a variável em js para php da mesma forma que você está utilizando o `ajax`. Porém, acho mais fácil, nesse caso, você alterar o titulo do documento através do `jquery`. Pelo que eu entendi do código a variável `imobiliaria` é a que você quer que esteja no `<title>`. Então ficaria assim:

```
 ...

    // Dentro da função mesmo...

    if (data.tipo == "f") {
        var imobiliaria = data.nome+" "+data.sobrenome;
        $('.nomeAnunciante').html(imobiliaria);
    } else {
        var imobiliaria = data.sobrenome;

        $('.nomeAnunciante').html(imobiliaria);
    }

    $(this).attr("title", imobiliaria); // aqui ele altera o título

...
```

Provavelmente isso vai dar certo. Se não der, comente aqui que eu dou um jeito

**EDIT**

*"houston we have a problem!"*

Em base no que você colocou até agora existe uma variável chamada `$title`que está em um arquivo php. O que você quer é lançar um conteúdo resgatado através do arquivo em js e passar esse conteúdo para essa variável, pois supostamente, você resolveria o problema do `SEO` e alteraria o `<title>` certo?. Existe uma forma de fazer isso, porém, isso não vai resolver o seu problema, pois o `php` é interpretado antes do `javascript` e a unica coisa que você fará é atualizar uma parte do código, mas a página carregada no servidor continua a mesma. Isso é a mesma coisa que o exemplo anterior, só que dando uma volta maior. Veja:

Esse é o código php (**resgataVariavel.php**)

```
<?php 
    @$title = $_POST['title'];
    echo json_encode($title);
?>
```

Essa é a **index.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imobiliaria = "Imobiliária Stack Overflow";
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'resgataVariavel.php',
        cache: false,
        data: { 'title': imobiliaria },
        success : function(retorno){
                 var resultado = JSON.parse(retorno);
                 document.title = resultado;
           }
    })

});
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
...
```

Através do ajax, passei o conteúdo da variável `imobiliaria` para a variável `$title`. Porém, no final, o título será alterado pelo javascript com `document.title = resultado;`.

O que você precisa fazer é pegar esse conteúdo através do php e lançar ele na variável  `$title` antes do javascipt ser executado.

Entenda, mesmo que essa variável do php `$title`estiver dentro da tag `<title></title>`, e eu usar o javascript para alterá-la, ainda assim não funcionaria, pois o servidor já "leu" o conteúdo antes de ela ser alterada pelo javascript.

**UMA SOLUÇÃO QUE PODE FUNCIONAR...**

Tente fazer desta forma:

```
 ... (código anterior)...

if (data.tipo == "f") {
        var imobiliaria = data.nome+" "+data.sobrenome;
        $('.nomeAnunciante').html(imobiliaria);
    } else {
        var imobiliaria = data.sobrenome;

        $('.nomeAnunciante').html(imobiliaria);
    }


    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'resgataVariavel.php',
        cache: false,
        data: { 'titulo': imobiliaria },
        success : function(retorno){
            document.write(retorno);
        },
    })

   ...(resto do código)...
```

Arquivo `resgataVariavel.php`

```
<?php 
    @$title = $_POST['titulo'];
    echo "<title>".$title."</title>";
?>
```

Repare que eu coloquei o php para incluir o `<title></title>`, não sei se vai funcionar para o SEO, pois quem escreve esse arquivo é o javascript. Mas é uma opção. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Andrei, funcionou da forma como me mostrou. Mas, infelizmente, para o SEO do google, setar o title ou qualquer outra metatag  por javascript não funciona, ao fazer a busca no google, o título que aparece da página não é esse editado por JS. Apenas as páginas que o título são elaboradas por PHP aparecem certo. E eu preciso, muito, fazer com que essa variável passe para uma variável PHP. Agradeço caso consiga me ajudar a fazer isso.

Comment: Ok... vou fazer da forma que vc precisa entao.. calma ae

Comment: @AlessandroBeiersdorf posta a pagina php ou html que tenha esse código. Vai ajudar muito

Comment: Esse última edição que fez também funcionou! Mas.. (sempre tem um mas haha) ao voltar ao arquivo js depois de ir até o arquivo php, as informações da imobiliária que já foram carregadas se esvaem, ficando apenas o título certo, sem nenhuma outra informação na página. Creio que seja a ordem da chamada da função, ou a resposta da chamada no sucess do ajax. Já tentei de tudo para que isso não acontecesse, mas não consegui. Desculpe a demora para responder.

Comment: @AlessandroBeiersdorf , rsrs... é assim mesmo... Mas antes de você corrigir isso. Veja se quando alterou o título, funcionou para o SEO. Entendeu?

Comment: @AlessandroBeiersdorf pois se não funcionar para o SEO, não vai adiantar nada arrumar o código.

Comment: E não esquece que você pode avaliar as respostas ok? Isso da um incentivo.. =)

Comment: Infelizmente não terei como atualizar no ar assim, pois, como mencionei, as informações da página não são carregadas, ficando apenas certo o título. Mas consegui de outro jeito :D

Answer (score 1):

Consegui pegar o valor de outro jeito, direto com o php, e setar no title, depois de muuito tentar também haha. Mas creio eu que a questão que estava procurando, que era passar o valor de uma variável js para php, foi resolvida na resposta acima, onde de fato deu certo, mas, como comentei, na volta para o arquivo JS, a página se atualiza e todas as informações carregadas se esvaem, ficando apenas o title certo. Mas enfim, o principal da questão foi resolvida e assim, encerro a questão aqui. Muito obrigado a todos e espero que a resposta acima dada pelo Andrei ajude muitos com a mesma dúvida. Grande abraço!

Comment: Sim... Foi como eu te falei.. Infelizmente o php é lido antes de você alterar a variavel. Entao, para o SEO, nao iria adiantar muito. =) Abraço